# SQL Groovy capture output of Print SQL statement

Tags: sql, redirect, jdbc, groovy, output

I'm using Gradle for build automation. Part of my automation process is to run [tSQLt](http://tsqlt.org) unit tests on SQL Azure databases. I use SQL Groovy through a JDBC driver. A failed test will be reported back to Gradle correctly, but doesn't give any information other than how man tests failed. The tSQLt framework provides a great summary, but uses PRINT to display it in SSMS.
I would really like to redirect the PRINT summary from tSQLt (basically a PRINT command in SQL Server) to a file, or even the screen. Just so it doesn't get lost.

I may not be using the correct connection method, but to run the unit tests and have them report errors back, I use:

```
sqlConnection.executeUpdate("exec tSQLt.runall")
```

There's probably a better method that will allow me to pipe the output, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: See this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116198/groovy-sql-eachrow-and-rows-method

Comment: Those methods require a recordset to be returned. tSQLt.runall does not return a recordset: it prints output to the console.